# How do I show that $b^8=a^3ba^{-3}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose $G$ is a group. I am trying to show that for $a,b\in G$, if $aba^{-1}=b^2$, then $b^8=a^3ba^{-3}$. 
I am not even sure if this is true but I found this in Artin's *Algebra*.

---

My work: $b^8=(b^2)^4=(aba^{-1})^4=ab^4a^{-1}=(ab)b^3a^{-1}=(b^2a)b^3a^{-1}(\text{ Using } ab=b^2a)=b^2ab^2(ba^{-1})=b^2ab^2(a^{-1}b^2)$ but I am only in circles from here.

Comment: Hint:$$a^nba^{-n}=b^{2^n}$$

Comment: why not just start with $aba^{-1}$, and multiply it by itself four times(left of right multiplication should work I think)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$aba^{-1}=b^2$. then $aba^{-1}aba^{-1}=b^2b^2\Rightarrow ab^2a^{-1}=b^4$ i.e. $b^4=a(aba^{-1})a^{-1}=a^2ba^{-2}$. Similarly then next we have

$$b^8=b^4b^4=a^2ba^{-2}a^2ba^{-2}=a^2b^2a^{-2}=a^2aba^{-1}a^{-2}=a^3ba^{-3}$$

Comment: Yes, this one is the most instructive. Maybe just through an identity in there for instructive purposes.

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$
b^8=(b^2.b^2)^2=(aba^{-1}aba^{-1})^2=(ab^2a^{-1})^2=(a(aba^{-1})a^{-1})^2=(a^2ba^{-2})^2=a^2b^2a^{-2}=a^3ba^{-3}
$$

Answer (score 0):

My most basic approach would be to notice that $aba^{-1}=b^2$ gives $ab=b^2a$. Then you can just keep pushing the a's from left to right. $$a^3ba^{-3}=a^2aba^{-3}=a^2b^2aa^{-3}=a^2b^2a^{-2}=aabba^{-2}=ab^2aba^{-2}=ab^2b^2aa^{-2}=ab^4a^{-1}=abb^3a^{-1}=b^2abb^2a^{-1}=b^2b^2abba^{-1}=b^4b^2aba^{-1}=b^6b^2aa^{-1}=b^8$$

Answer (score 0):

On one side, you have $b^4 = a b^2 a^{-1}$ and $b^8 = a b^4 a^{-1}$ by squaring.

On the other, you have $a^3 b a^{-3} = a^2 (a b a^{-1}) a^{-2} = a^2 b^2 a^{-2} = a (a b^2 a^{-1}) a^{-1} = a b^4 a^{-1}$.